# Update postDate in real time

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, real-time

So i make a script that shows new posts in real time like Twitter and Facebook. That was easy i just grab the last postID and chek for new every 30 sec but i dont how to change the postDate. If it was only one post ok , but how to do it if there is 20 posts in one page ?

Comment: Code? Markup? fiddle? something???

Comment: I dont have any code i just dont have the basic idea how to do it..

Comment: Without you explicitly explaining what `postDate` does it is hard to answer your question. Is it the time of the last post or each posts individual time?

Comment: i want to update eachs individual time. in the post meta its says posted 12 min ago and i want this to change in real time to 25 min ago .. 1 hour and so on

Comment: I do have a time class that convert unix timestamp to human time but how to change the post creation time when the real time progress. Like in here it says 3 hours ago after the comment based on the real time right? so how to make this change in all comments or post. First i have to get each post creation time then after x sec to change the human time of the post or comment with ajax.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't refresh or make ajax requests every 30 sec best way is to use websockets.

The thing with websockets is that you create a connection client with server and than when something new is posted the server himself will tell the client that something new was posted.
That way you dont make any wasteful requests every X seconds.

Check out HTML5 WebSockets for real time updates

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_websocket.htm